# Dummy variable on a vector with scikit onehotencoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorization

Let say I have a vector of integers, where every integers corresponds to a category:

```
A = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1]
```

I know how many categories I have. This vector is one of the columns of my X dataset which will end in the logistic regression model.

Is it possible to use the sciki-tlearn function *onehotencoder* to obtain something like:

> 0 0 0 1 (when 1)
>   0 0 1 0 (when 2)
>   0 1 0 0 (when 3)
>   1 0 0 0 (when whatever)

or even better

> 0 0 0
>   0 0 1
>   0 1 0
>   1 0 0

?

When I try to pass such a vector to onehotencoder I obtain this error: `need more than 1 value to unpack`.

Furthermore: I suppose that if I have 'NULL' records I should first transform them in a number: is there a fast way to do it, like `A(find(A=='NULL'))=123`?

Thank you for your help.
Francesco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OneHotEncoder` input needs to be 2-d, not 1-d (it expects a set of samples).

```
>>> X = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1]]
```

Let's suppose that your categorical features can all take on four values:

```
>>> n_values = np.repeat(4, len(X[0]))
>>> n_values
array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

Then `OneHotEncoder` works fine:

```
>>> oh = OneHotEncoder(n_values=n_values)
>>> Xt = oh.fit_transform(X)
>>> Xt.toarray()
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,
         0.]])
>>> Xt.shape
(1, 40)
```

It produces one dummy variable too many for each input variable, which is a bit wasteful. I've no idea what you mean by this `NULL` stuff since I don't know what your data looks like. You might want to open a separate question for that.

Comment: Than that needs to be reshaped to (10,4), and it should work. Right?
That's a solution, thank you!
I wonder why it needs 2-D or more while it's doing something that should work (theoretically) for 1-D (unless I'm missing some logical-mathematical steps).
My question now is: if I have more than one column that represents numerical categories, can I put them both in the same onehotencoder? Let's say the first column has 5 categories and the second has 4 categories, 10 rows: in the end I should obtain an array (10,9). Does onehotencoder do that? (thank you again!)

Comment: @foebu I don't understand why you'd want to reshape that, at least not if you want to feed it to an estimator. It needs to be 2-d because everything in scikit-learn is batch-oriented. For the second question, yes, that can be done, please see the docstring for details.

Comment: I'm using not only categories. I've some features which are quantities and they are columns of the dataset so I was thinking to concatenate the result of the onehotencoder with the other features, and use that as training set for the logistic regression.

I was playing with your code, and strange enough, if I change the last number of the X list to 4, the fit_transform doesn't work and I get a "column index exceedes matrix dimensions"; while if I change that in a 2 or 3 it works.
X = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4]] doesn't work, 
X = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3]] this works

Comment: @foebu There's a parameter called, I think, `categorical_features` which controls this. What you describe could be a bug; if you have time to investigate, you might want to submit an issue at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues.

Comment: The parameter categorical_feature is cool, in this way I can give as argument the whole dataset and just put in categorical_feature the indexes of the categorical feature. This should solve my problem. 

Furthermore: using X = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3]] and then reshaping doesn't work: it encodes wrongly the last three values. Using X = [[1],[2], [3], [3], [2], [3], [4], [2], [1], [4]] works perfectly with n_values='auto' and it gives me a (10,4) array without reshaping. Is that normal? I'll signal it anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry for the double comment: basically it works how I want when I give it a column vector. Let suppose that X=array([1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 2]), if I give as argument X=X.transpose() it works, and it returns that array (10,4) that I was looking for. Cool!